# How to connect to mySQL docker instance from another docker instance on the same machine

Tags: python, mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have setup mySQL through docker using below commands:

1. docker network create -d bridge mynetwork
2. docker run -p 3306:3306 --network mynetwork  --name mysql  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=5895 -d mysql:latest

I'm using a python connector to connect.

```
host=127.0.0.1
port=3306
user=root
root=5895
mysql.connector.connect(host=host, port=port, user=user, password=password, database=database)
```

Now this works fine if I run my python file locally (not on docker). Now I want to create a dockerized version.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /twitter-alpha

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY /constants ./constants
COPY /connectors ./connectors
COPY backfillFollowed.py .
COPY backfillUsers.py .
COPY .env .

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install vim
```

I then build docker instance with `docker build -t twitter-alpha . --no-cache` and startup this docker instance with `docker run -itd -p 3000:3000 --name test --network mynetwork twitter-alpha`. When I create a docker image for my python files (Dockerfile below) and run the same python script I get `mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (99)`

If I switch 127.0.0.1 with the IP found from `docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' a627c65ddc3c` it works, but this seems like a bad approach since IP will change every time the container is created.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to set host= nameOfDockerInstance

Took me a while